# C# case statement error cannot implicitly convert string to char

Tags: c#, char, switch-statement, console-application

Okay so the assignment I am working on is supposed to take 7 characters letters and numbers only no symbols and turn them into a 7 digit phone number. My assignment says I need to use switch statements and have a case statement for each digit. I am just trying to get this to at least work with the first character before moving on to the rest. The conversions are based on a standard phone keypad. A, B, or C would be 2, D,E,F would be 3 and so on. This is my first time using case statements, so I am not even sure if I am doing this right. The error I am receiving is "Cannot implicitly convert type string to char". My questions is am I even doing this case statement right? If so how to I get this to compile properly and If not how to I make is so that when someone enters an A, B, or C it converts to a "2"?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("****Phone Dialing Program****\n");

        char char1 = default(char);
        char char2 = default(char);
        char char3 = default(char);
        char char4 = default(char);
        char char5 = default(char);
        char char6 = default(char);
        char char7 = default(char);


        GetInput(ref char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7);
        ProcessInput();
        //ToDigit(ref char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7);
        ShowResults();


        Console.Read();
    }

    static void GetInput(ref char char1, char char2, char char3, char char4, char char5, char char6, char char7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your first character:");
        char1 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your second character:");
        char2 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your third character:");
        char3 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your fourth character:");
        char4 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your fifth character:");
        char5 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your sixth character:");
        char6 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your seventh character:");
        char7 = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        ToDigit(ref char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7);

    }

    static void ProcessInput()
    {
    }

    static void ToDigit(ref char char1, char char2, char char3, char char4, char char5, char char6, char char7)
    {
        switch(char1)
        {

            case "A": //all of these cases come up with the error
            case "a":
            case "B":
            case "b":
            case "C":
            case "c":
            case "2": Console.WriteLine("test");
                break;
            default: Console.WriteLine("this test did not work :(");
                break;
        }

    }

    static void ShowResults()
    {
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, `"A"` means one letter `string`. To get char, use `'`: `'A'`.

Your `switch` cases should be:

```
switch(char1)
{
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
    case 'B':
    case 'b':
    case 'C':
    case 'c':
    case '2': Console.WriteLine("test");
        break;
    default: Console.WriteLine("this test did not work :(");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Dang! Its always something so simple :p Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even I used ' ' tags for the char to iterate through switch statement, it didn't work. Don't know why but I solved the issue by declaring char after case and using "when" helper and check the char equalisation, and it worked. Sample code was like this, hope this helps someone out there.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempCharArray.Length; i++) 
        {
            switch (tempCharArray[i])
            {
                // Point
                case char _point when _point == '.':
                    Debug.Log("Point is detected");
                    break;

                // Numbers
                case char _one when _one == '1':
                    Debug.Log("1 is detected");
                    break;

                case char _two when _two == '2':
                    Debug.Log("Point detected");
                    break;
                /* so on..*/

                default:
                
                break;


            }
        }
```

Comment: Due to the fact you reply to a six year old question you need to mention version numbers to which your solution applies when tested. EoR.